# TableViewCell not displaying data

Tags: swift, storyboard, tableview, cell

I have a table view cell that is supposed to display just a label but it wont show anything at all when I run my app. I have even tried changing the textLabels within my code but still nothing. I tried changing the cell background color as well which worked in the storyboard but when I actually run the app nothing changes. I have disconnected my view controller entirely to see if my code was the issue and still nothing happened so from what I see is its not my code but the view itself. I could be wrong though. Here is what my view loks like now:   [tableviewdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72jsm.png)

```
//
//  TableViewController.swift
//  streamingVideo
//
//  Created by Connor Woodford on 5/15/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Connor Woodford. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

struct Courses: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let location: String

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



    var courses = [Courses]()

    @IBOutlet weak var arg: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchJSON()


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    func fetchJSON() {

        let urlString = "http://homevideostuff.192.168.1.14.xip.io:8888/getClasses.php"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to get data from URL:", err)
                    return
                } else {

                    print("Loaded URL")
                }

                guard let data = data else { return }

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    self.courses = try decoder.decode([Courses].self, from: data)
                    print(self.courses)

                } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Failed to decode JSON", jsonErr)
                }
            }

            }.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return courses.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let sweet = courses[indexPath.row]

        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

        cell.textLabel?.text = "sdafasdfs"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = sweet.location

        print("azDFASDFASDFAS")
        return cell
}
}
```

Comment: You need to provide your code for us to be able to help.

Comment: OK here is the code but i don't think that is where the issue resides. The tableview is completely dissconnected from the code as of right now and it still wont display anything such as images, labels and textfields etc.

Comment: You're not setting your table view delegates.

Comment: set the dataSource in viewDidLoad and reload the table inside the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }
```

You need to return at least 1 section, as a row is a child of a section

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload data after fetch `course`  , your table name is `arg`

`self.arg.reloadData()` when finish fetching `courses`

after that line

```
 self.courses = try decoder.decode([Courses].self, from: dat
--> self.arg.reloadData()
```

Comment: I created an outlet for my table view to reload the data. I set the table view as my datasource and delegate but when i run the app nothing shows up. Not even the background color I set for the cell.

Comment: you have to write this  `self.arg.reloadData()`  as answer above and make sure that course have data

Comment: How is it though that I cant even change the background color of my cell through the storyboard? I added the self.arg.reloadData() and still nothing. The identifiers on the storyboard match up with the identifiers in my table view function as well.